# Inferred type is Fragment but Context was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I am trying to create a simple app where the user can enter text into a EditText field. By pressing a button, the input is then saved into a SQLite database.

I have followed (and tried to adapt to my application) the guide at the following link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-sqlite-database-in-kotlin/

However, when running the application in Android Studio, I get the error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is AddRecipeFragment but Context was expected
```

My AddRecipeFragment.kt reads:

```
package com.example.recipy

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.recipy.databinding.FragmentAddRecipeBinding


class AddRecipeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAddRecipeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentAddRecipeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

//        val saveRecipeButton = findViewById(R.id.save_recipe_button) as Button
        binding.saveRecipeButton.setOnClickListener{

            val db = DBHelper(this, null)
            val name = binding.recipeNameTextInput.text.toString()

            db.addRecipe(name)

            Toast.makeText(this, name + " added to database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            binding.recipeNameTextInput.text.clear()
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

and my fragment_add_recipe.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AddRecipeFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/recipe_name_text_input"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_recipe_button"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:text="Name\n\n"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipe_name_text_input"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and DBHelper.kt:

```
package com.example.recipy

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

public class DBHelper(context: Context, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    // below is the method for creating a database by a sqlite query
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

        val query = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                NAME_COl + " TEXT," + ")")
        
        db.execSQL(query)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        // this method is to check if table already exists
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    // This method is for adding data in our database
    fun addRecipe(name : String){
        
        val values = ContentValues()
        
        values.put(NAME_COl, name)
        
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)

        db.close()
    }


    companion object{
        // here we have defined variables for our database

        // below is variable for database name
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "RECIPY_DB"

        // below is the variable for database version
        private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1

        // below is the variable for table name
        val TABLE_NAME = "recipes_table"

        // below is the variable for id column
        val ID_COL = "id"

        // below is the variable for name column
        val NAME_COl = "name"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have followed (and tried to adapt to my application) the guide at the following link

That guide does not use fragments. It instantiates `DBHelper` from an `Activity`. `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`.

> However, when running the application in Android Studio, I get the error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is AddRecipeFragment but Context was expected`

You copied and pasted the line to instantiate `DBHelper`, but you pasted it into a `Fragment`. `Fragment` does not extend from `Context`, so `this` is not a `Context`, which `DBHelper` expects.

You can use `requireContext()` instead of `this`:

```kotlin
val db = DBHelper(requireContext(), null)
```

That being said, I really recommend that you learn Android using more complete resources, such as books and courses. That guide is focused on one tiny aspect of Android app development, and the recommendations that it makes are fairly poor. Whether you try [my free books](https://commonsware.com/catalog) or something else, find resources that will teach you modern Android app development, including things like threading (e.g., Kotlin coroutines), reactive APIs (e.g., Kotlin flows), lifecycle management (e.g., `ViewModel`), and similar topics.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I started reading your book (the "learning by doing one"). So far very useful (although I came to a halt for issues with the gradle version, which I was not able to solve yet)

Comment: @gicanzo: That book is ~3 years old. The simplest (if annoying) solution is to use the Arctic Fox edition of Android Studio, which is what the book used. Everything will then be consistent with the book. However, it means that you will be a bit out of date with the current shipping Android Studio version.

Comment: would it be too difficult to fix the code to make it run with the latest verion? Or would there be a lot to change? I updated gradle after Android Studio suggested it, but this caused another chain of version mismatches that I could not come on top of

Comment: @gicanzo: For an experienced developer, it might not be too bad. For a newcomer, it might be complicated.